# How is it possible to specify the encoding of a document inside the document?

Tags: html, character-encoding

One way to specify the encoding of an HTML document is by sending the appropriate headers. However, a fallback approach is to declare the encoding inline via a meta tag. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <title>Foo bar</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello, world!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

But to read the document and determine the encoding, must one not already know the encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as no non-ASCII characters appear before that `<meta>` tag, the browser can assume that it's ASCII or UTF8, and it will read correctly until that point.
This is why that `<meta>` tag should be *before* the `<title>`.

If it's UTF16, the browser can figure that out by trying to read characters like `<`.

Comment: More exactly, it can find out `UTF16` by the BOM or (if there's none) by the bunch of `0x00` bytes interlacing the actual characters.